# Tomcat access logs - are failed requests included?

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

We have a RESTful web service (Java, hosted in Tomcat). From time to time it fails (not every week). When it fails, Java CPU consumption goes to 100% and it takes all available memory. It does not finish by itself. I have to restart the server.

There is nothing suspicious in Tomcat access logs. I guess one of our users could submit a very "heavy" request which brought the server down. Is it possible this request is not in Tomcat logs since it never finished?

Many thanks

Maxim

Answer (score 0):

It is more likely that your Tomcat process is leaking memory until it got no more free memory. Try to log the heap size with each request, and then notice if it keeps growing.

The tomcat class loader can leak memory, especially if you use the "automatic deploy" feature.

```
long freeMem=Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
long maxMem=Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
long totalMem=Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
```

And then log freeMem/MaxMem and totalMem. If max keeps growing you got a leak.

Edit: And to answer your question. That depend on exactly how tomcat fails, and how you have set up logging. But with our system(A rather default apache mod_proxy=>tomcat, there are some fatal tomcat errors which are only logged in catalina.out

Comment: Sorry, it happens suddenly, and very rarely. We use NewRelic - it shows Java memory on charts. There is no gradual memory leak.

Comment: It still really sounds exactly like a memory leak. Even the most heavy single request should not kill tomcat, because there are  multiple threads to handle other requests. So if it was a single request it would just slow down, not die.

Comment: Does NewRelic also show the max heap size? Because we once had a tomcat system where the max heap keept growing, while the memory used by the app did not grow. So it would run a garbadge collection, which would increase heap from 700MB to 800MB, and then after the collection there would be 650MB free. So there were no reason for it to grow the heap, but it did until it reached max heap size and died.

Comment: NewRelic shows "Used heap" and "Committed heap". I am not sure about  the max heap size.

Comment: BTW the garbage collection started about the same time.